# Trying to add a Data ID Column that maps back by ID

Tags: sql

I am using the below query to pull back a group of codes by a parent ID and simply want to add a column that identifies each group that each belongs to so that I can easily use this to pivot out data...

```
select
s.DATE, p.NBR, p.parent_id 
from table_a, batch_table p
WHERE p.parent_id in
--GROUP1
('1234'
,'9876'
  --GROUP2
,'2345'
,'4567'

--GROUP3
,'3000'
,'7896'
and p._nbr=s._nbr
```

Currently looks like this

```
S.date     p,nbr        p.parent ID
20210518    92          1234
20210518    92          9876
20210518    92          3000
20210518    92          2345
```

Would like this

```
S.date     p,nbr        p.parent ID  **PARENTGROUP**
20210518    92          1234            **GROUP1**
20210518    92          9876            **GROUP1**
20210518    92          3000            **GROUP3**
20210518    92          2345            **GROUP2**
```

Comment: This makes no sense.  Why are you using a Cartesian product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `case statement`:

```
select s.DATE, p.NBR, p.parent_id  
, case when parent_id in ('1234','9876') then 'Group 1'
       when parent_id in ('2345','4567') then 'Group 2'
       when parent_id in ('3000','7896') then 'Group 3'
 end as PARENTGROUP
from table_a s
join batch_table p on p._nbr=s._nbr
WHERE p.parent_id in ('1234','9876','2345','4567','3000','7896')
```

also always use explicit join